# Robot framework ride- Why log and report active are inactive when I run in the second time?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

As title,

first time picture:

[image: run first time]
As picture,  log and report are active.

---

second time picture:
[image: [run second time].

As picture, log and report are inactive.

---

And I find the reason. I find that after I run it, chromedriver.exe on Windows Task Manager is still running. Therefore, I cancel chromedriver.exe after first run, and run second time,  log and report are active.

However, if I always cancel it manually, it's too inconvenient...
Do anyone have some suggestions to solve this problems?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Stop the chromedriver in the [test teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown).

Comment: Thanks.
Do you mean the keyword "Close Browser"? I try it, and it stops the chromedriver.exe. However, I want to stay the browser. How can I do?

Comment: Why do you want it? You should tear down the test environment after the tests have been executed.

Comment: I just want to stay the final result to show.
I understand, thank you for your reply^^

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by stopping chromedriver.exe in test teardown!

1.Call the OperatingSystem libirary

2.Use:

```
RUN    taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe
```